# Parsing div elements with Nokogiri

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, xpath, nokogiri

The following code successfully extracts tid and term data:

(answered generously by Uri Agassi)

```
for i in (1..10)
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://somewebsite.com/#{i}/"))
  tids =  doc.xpath("//div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '),' thing ')]").collect {|node|    node['data-thing-id']}
  terms = doc.xpath("//div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '),' col_a ')]").collect {|node| node.text.strip }

  tids.zip(terms).each do |tid, term|
    puts tid+" "+term
  end
end
```

from the following sample html:

```
<div class="thing text-text" data-thing-id="29966403">
  <div class="thinguser"><i class="ico ico-water ico-blue"></i>
    <div class="status">in 7 days
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ignore-ui pull-right"><input type="check box" >
  </div>
  <div class="col_a col text">
    <div class="text">foobar
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col_b col text">
    <div class="text">foobar desc
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I wanted to pull status (the "in 7 days" string) info in the same fashion, what's the best way to do that? I can't seem to figure it out.

Would someone be kind enough to explain in detail what the tids and terms assignment lines are actually doing? I don't get it and the Nokogiri documentation doesn't seem to cover this.

Big thanks in advance.

~Chris

Answer (score 1):

I'm all about using css selectors in nokogiri. Something like this should work.

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://somewebsite.com/#{i}/"))
seven_days = doc.css('status').content
```

Comment: Thank you but it is saying the .content method is undefined: in `<main>': undefined method `content' for []:Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet (NoMethodError)

Comment: @user1117603 The selector is wrong and should be '.status'. That will return a match of all matching nodes. So the last line should be *seven_days = doc.css('.status').first.content* or *seven_days = doc.at_css('.status').content* if you only need the first node matching the selector.

Comment: @Pafjo Thank you but I still get the same error: ./scrape_next_rep.rb:15:in `<main>': undefined method `content' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Comment: @Pafjo Any idea why `puts doc.at_css('div.col_a > div.text').text` works yet `puts doc.at_css('div.thing > div.thinguser > div.status').text` doesn't?

Comment: @user1117603 that's weird! Both examples works for me when I try them with you sample html. I'm using Ruby 1.9.2p318, Nokogiri 1.6.1 with  libxml2 at 2.9.1_0. Are you reading the content from file or over network?

Comment: @Pafjo I"m on Nokogirl 1.6.1, libxml 2.2.7.3, ruby 1.9.3p392 on MacOSX 10.7.5 and i'm pulling from the network as opposed to a local file.  Will try a local file and on a linux box. Thanks.