# Extract this string using Nokogiri

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, xpath, nokogiri

Using xpath or css, can someone please suggest a way to extract this string:

"in 7 days"

from:

```
<div class="thing text-text" data-thing-id="29966403">
  <div class="thinguser"><i class="ico ico-water ico-blue"></i>
    <div class="status">in 7 days
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ignore-ui pull-right"><input type="check box" >
  </div>
  <div class="col_a col text">
    <div class="text">foobar
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col_b col text">
    <div class="text">foobar desc
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The xpath from chrome looks like:

```
 //*[@id="content"]/div/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div
```

Thank you in advance,
~Chris

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing div elements with Nokogiri](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23356121/parsing-div-elements-with-nokogiri)

Answer (score 1):

Use `at_css`:

```
doc.at_css('div.thing > div.thinguser > div.status').text
```

Comment: Thank you, but i keep getting this error: ./scrape_next_rep.rb:16:in `<main>': undefined method `text' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError). I would be greatly appreciative if you can point in right direction.

Comment: @user1117603 That's because the CSS selector didn't find anything matched. Ensure the document is loaded properly by Nokogiri and try to refactor the CSS selector.

Comment: Will do. I believe the doc is loaded properly because I'm able to other elements from it fine like data-thing-id and "foobar" (using xpath to get those). For some reason it doesn't work when i use doc.at_css. Thank you again.

Comment: @Aria-shaw Baffled that `puts doc.at_css('div.col_a > div.text').text` works but `puts doc.at_css('div.thing > div.thinguser > div.status').text` does not.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = %q{ 
  <html>
   <body>
    <div class="thing text-text" data-thing-id="29966403">
    <div class="thinguser"><i class="ico ico-water ico-blue"></i>
      <div class="status">in 7 days
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ignore-ui pull-right"><input type="check box" >
    </div>
    <div class="col_a col text">
      <div class="text">foobar
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col_b col text">
      <div class="text">foobar desc
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
}

doc = Nokogiri::XML(html)
status = doc.at_css('.status')

puts status.text
```